# Decrement Max Value From Map?

Tags: apex, map, sort

How can I sort a `Map` based on `value`? Here is the `Map` structure:

```
Map<DateTime, Integer> AppDetails = new Map<DateTime, Integer>();
```

And the data:

> 2016-10-1,10
>   2016-10-2,3
>   2016-10-3,13
>   2016-10-6,40
>   2016-10-4,60
>   2016-10-8,40

How can I sort `AppDetails` by value and get the highest value(`60`) out of it and return the date(`2016-10-4`) to the calling function and decrement the original value by 1 (in this case it will be `59`) in the `Map`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your post to use valid syntax?

Comment: updated my post.. please see

Comment: still looking for best solution.. thank all for your suggestion/help..

Comment: You seem to be having an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info) here. Perhaps step back and try to describe at a high level what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt:

```
Map<Date, Integer> appDetails = new Map<Date, Integer>
{
    Date.newInstance(2016,10,1) => 10,
    Date.newInstance(2016,10,2) => 3,
    Date.newInstance(2016,10,3) => 13,
    Date.newInstance(2016,10,6) => 40,
    Date.newInstance(2016,10,4) => 60,
    Date.newInstance(2016,10,8) => 40
};

List<Integer> detailsList = new List<Integer>( appDetails.values() );
detailsList.sort();
Integer maxNumber = detailsList[detailsList.size() - 1];
Integer maxCount = 1;

while (detailsList[detailsList.size() - 1 - maxCount] == maxNumber)
    maxCount++;

for (Date d:appDetails.keySet())
{
    if(appDetails.get(d) == maxNumber)
    {
        appDetails.put(d, maxNumber - 1);
        maxCount--;
        if(maxCount == 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

It could handle multiple members with max value (if there are more than one) and will decrease each by 1. It also breaks the loop after all members with max value were updated.

Answer (score 5):

Maps are an example of an unordered collection, which cannot be sorted.

However, If you're open to writing code and spending additional time developing your idea, you can build something that should work.

From what I see, you don't absolutely require a Map, it was just the closest feature provided by Salesforce that you could find.

Instead of a Map, I'd suggest making an Apex class to hold your data that implements [the comparable interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm). You can then store these results in a List (which is an ordered collection).

A quick example to get you going

```
class DatePlusInteger implements Comparable{
    public Date myDate;
    public Integer count;

    public Integer compareTo(Object compareObj){
        DatePlusInteger comparisonTarget = (DatePlusInteger)compareObj;

        if(comparisonTarget.Integer === count){
            return 0;
        }else if(comparisonTarget.Integer < count){
            // This instance of our object has a greater count than the one
            //   we are comparing against. So, return positive 1
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Implementing the Comparable interface will allow you to call `List.sort()`. Doing so will sort the records in ascending order, meaning that your largest count will be the last element of your list.

The last element of a list is pretty easily retrieved using the List's `size()` method

```
// Apex collections are 0-indexed, so when using size(), we must subtract 1
// Otherwise, we'd get an out-of-bounds exception
Object lastElement = someList[someList.size() - 1];
```

I'm fairly certain that retrieving an object from a List returns a reference to the object instance in that list. To put it simply, that means that you should be able to grab the date, decrement the count, and not have to worry about anything else.

```
lastElement.myDate;
lastElement.count -= 1;
```

A slightly better approach would be to add a getter to `DatePlusCount` that would take care of the decrementing for you.

```
class DatePlusCount{
    /* other lines omitted */
    public Date getDate(){
        count -=1;
        return myDate;
    }
}
```

usage is pretty simple

```
// Assuming List<DatePlusCount> myList is initialized elsewhere...
myList.sort();
Date targetDate = myList[myList.size()-1].getDate();
```

The only thing left that you'd need to concern yourself with would be to make sure that you always call `sort()` on the List *every single time* before trying to retrieve the `Date` associated with the maximum count.

Swapping the `return 1;` and `return -1;` in the `compareTo(Object compareObj)` method could make things even simpler still. That should effectively cause the list sorting to return in *decending* order, meaning the max value would be at index 0;

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option. At first I thought `Comparable` would make the most sense, but this might be faster. I haven't profiled them, that's just a guess.

```
public static void decrementMaxValue(Map<Datetime, Integer> input)
{
    Datetime maxKey;
    Integer maxValue;
    for (Datetime key : input.keySet())
    {
        Integer value = input.get(key);
        if (maxValue == null || (value != null && value > maxValue))
        {
            maxValue = value;
            maxKey = key;
        }
    }
    if (maxKey != null && maxValue != null)
        input.put(maxKey, maxValue - 1);
}
```

You could probably program this method to be less defensive against NPE. I'll leave that to you to decide.

I profiled the three approaches recommended so far and this one does seem to be the fastest. Here is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/aalarson/fcc3284906d39e687e83bb051ed8324c) detailing my methodology. Your mileage may vary. My results (milliseconds per hundred calls):

```
method                  Trial_1  Trial_2  Trial_3  Trial_4  Trial_5  Average
decrementMaxComparable       32       33       31       28       26     30.0
decrementMaxInvertMap        17       18       16       19       19     17.8
decrementMaxTrackValue       11       10       11       11       12     11.0
```

Comment: It's unlikely to make a difference in most workloads, but I do think that `List.sort()` uses a mergesort algorithm for sorting, which would be O(n log n) on average vs O(n).

Comment: @Derek Sorry, I studied French in college. I think you're saying this approach would be *faster* than sort?

Comment: i have question here  -1) after comparing we're adding new record again back to the Map with val -1 , where are we deleting the existing record ?

Comment: @kiran First of all, a `record` typically indicates an instance of an `sObject`. That term is completely out of place here. Second of all, what are you talking about deleting anything? Your OP never makes any mention of such behavior.

Comment: @Adrian - sorry for the confusion, because of input.put(maxKey, maxValue - 1); this line i got confused . i just want to mention here - I want to update the existing map record by -1 if its higher. .put method is for adding the new records. correct me if i'm wrong here

Comment: You overwrite the key if it's already in the map. It only adds to the map if the key doesn't already exist. I suggest you do some basic research on how hash tables work to better understand.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You are correct. For some reason I thought that `sort()` was faster than your approach (spoiler: I was wrong). I was using 'big-O' notation from complexity theory. Loosely speaking, the ordering (from fastest to slowest) looks like O(1) -> O(log n) -> O(n) -> O(n log n) -> O(n^2) -> O(2^n). It's a quick notation for describing relative performance of a piece of code with a given number of inputs.

Comment: Right, I'm vaguely familiar with `Big O Notation`, just not super familiar with the details. But it does seem obvious a bigger number in the parens is worse for performance. Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually surprised that the `Comparable` implementation ended up being that much slower, especially compared to the map inversion method.

Comment: Granted, this is a pretty small map we're talking about here. Different datasets may well produce different results. Feel free to fork the Gist. :)

Comment: Just a though how about if i can create Map object with <Integer , Object> and object contain date, no_of_record and other parameter , Here key is unique value like (1,2,3) i will loop though the object value to find the highest no_of_record value and if found return the Key + Object ( which contain date,no_of_records and other parameters )

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to create a new Map by using AppDetails Map. Like :

`Map<integer, date> details = new Map<integer, date>();
for(date d : AppDetails.keySet())
{
     details.put(AppDetails.get(d), d);
}`

Now by using new map you can get set. Like :
`Set<Integer> values = details.keyset();`

Now change Set into List.In List you can apply sort() method to sort values in List.'

`List<Integer> sortedList = new List<Integer>(values).sort();`

Last element is your Max value and by this value you can corresponding date 
using details map. Like :

`Date d = details.get(sortedList[sortedList.size() - 1]);`

Comment: This will run into a problem when two dates end up having the same integer associated with them. This could be fixed by making the `details` map one of `Map<Integer, List<Date>>`, but that would also increase the complexity of using and maintaining the `details` map.

Comment: I think this issue will remain with all solutions, in comparable also.

Comment: With `Comparable`, if two records are equal to one another, using `List.sort()` will put one record ahead of the other using some unknown, arbitrary condition (perhaps based on the hash of the record, I've really no idea). No information in the List will be lost or overwritten.

Comment: What I think, in my solution where we are creating new map, we are trying to put duplicate value in map and I think map internally uses hashcode. I am not sure that I am right or wrong.

Comment: You are correct that the keys of a map are stored as a hashcode (an Apex map is basically just a Java Hashmap in the back-end). That doesn't change the fact that if you execute `details.put(10, '2016-8-25');` and then `details.put(10, '2016-7-1');` the date `2016-8-25` has been overwritten in the map, and can no longer be retrieved.